# Debootstrap /usr/sbin/debootstrap: 481: : Permission denied Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, debian, debootstrap

I'm trying to create an `arm` debian `rootfs` into a Pen Drive which I mounted in `/mnt`.

I execute:

```
sudo debootstrap –arch=armel –foreign stable /mnt
```

But then it just creates a file in `/mnt/-foreign/debootstrap/debootstrap.log` which has the following line:

```
/usr/sbin/debootstrap: 481: : Permission denied
```

Comment: Welcome, it seems to me that your options are malformed, they [should be prepended by double dashes, as in `--arch, --foreign`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debootstrap/debootstrap.8.en.html#OPTIONS), not just one.

Comment: Please show the full log. (`debootstrap.log`)

Comment: Yes, the double dashes were the only problem here. Now it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As said, the way to solve this problem is to simply add double dashes in the debootstrap command

And it becomes like this:

```
sudo debootstrap --arch=armel --foreign stable /mnt
```